# Angular dockerize is not running on local port?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

i have an angular app that i am trying to make it dockerize so with the below Dockerfile it is building an image , how do i run this app now locally for the port that i exposed `4200` i am new to docker stuff any help will be appreciated this will be without nginx.

Dockerfile

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM node:14 as builder
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN  npm install --production 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:14

USER 9000:9000

# create the base directory
WORKDIR /apps/nodejs/gcp/

ENV HOME=/apps/nodejs/gcp/
# set the home directory

COPY --from=builder node_modules ./node_modules

COPY package.json ./

# copy readme.md
COPY README.md ./
# copy the dist to the home dir
COPY dist ./dist

# DO NOT COPY THE CERTS AND CONFIG FOLDER IN THIS IMAGE. THESE WILL BE INJECTED BY KUBERNETES.
# IN ORDER TO RUN THIS IMAGE IN LOCAL MOUNT THE HOST NODECERT AND CONFIG FOLDER TO THE DOCKER
# docker run -p 9082:9082 --rm \
#--env "NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=true NODE_ENV=production PORT=9082 \
#LOGCONSOLE=true CONFIGBASEPATH=/apps/nodejs/gcp/config/ CERTSBASEPATH=/apps/nodejs/gcp/nodecerts" \
#-v /apps/nodejs/gcp/nodecerts:/apps/nodejs/gcp/nodecerts -v /apps/nodejs/gcp/config/:/apps/nodejs/gcp/config/ <image name>

# TO GO INSIDE THE RUNNING CONTAINER
# docker container exec -it <container id> sh

#BUILDING Docker
# docker build -t <image name> .
# <image name>: all lowercase and if needed separated by hypen(-). eg redis-service




# port the server will be listening to.
EXPOSE 4200
```

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

Answer (score 1):

## Generate the build of the application

Use this command:

```
npm run build
```

Create a Dockerfile inside the build output folder and add this code in **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:latest
MAINTAINER yournick@winter.com
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Finally build the docker image using this command:

```
docker build -t angular-dist-project:v1 .
```

Now run the image using this command:

```
docker run -d --name angular-app-container -p 2021:80 angular-dist-project:v1
```

Now go to browser and navigate **http://your-ip:2021**:

```
http://localhost:2021
```

Result: angular app is successfully dockerized

> **NOTE**: Do not forget and
> remember that this only is an alternative, exist anothers many ways!

I hope you understand.
All the best

Comment: After buil the project, to running an angular app it is necesary a web server.